# Map Control form Client Side to Server Side HTML ASP Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have some problem about Map control name from client side to server side in HTML in Client side I have control MyTextBox

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="get" action="Example2.aspx" >     
        <div>
            <input id="MyTextBox" type="text" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

and i user Jquery post data to server side

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Defaul.aspx/Myfunction",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        // alert(objEmployee);                        
    },                   
    data: '{"ID":"' + ID + '","FirstName":"' + FirstName + '"}',
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }
}); // $.ajax
```

In the server side I want to get control name is "MyTextBox", how can I get it?

Comment: First thing - Your question is not clear!! what you want to get? The whole control or just the value of the control? Second thing - Your ajax data is not properly specified it should be like - `data: {"ID":ID, "FirstName" : FirstName},`

Comment: First of all you are not sending any `formdata` to the server side and as per me your should get your `data` as parameter in your method `GetDate`. and from next time please edit the question and not post it as comment.

Comment: if it is `asp.net`, can't you use `asp.net TextBox` control?